# Wildcard not working in subprocess call using shlex

Tags: python, subprocess, shlex

Language: Python v2.6.2

OS: AIX 5.3

I'm using Python to restore some files from a backup to a test system - all commands are called in the manner below, however some just plain don't want to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, shlex

cmd = 'sudo rm -rf /work/TEST/*'
arg = shlex.split(cmd)

# This does not work
p = subprocess.Popen(arg)

# This, however, works just fine
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

If I remove the *'s from the commands they work fine (well, they work as they should without the wildcards, which is unfortauntely not what I want).

I really do not want to use shell=True for obvious security reasons, however there are a couple of other commands that basically do the same thing. If there is a wildcard in the command it just won't work - it executes without error, just doesn't do anything.

Interestingly the following command (parsed through shlex):

```
sudo mv /work/testrestore/production/* /work/TESTC
```

Produces the following:

mv: 0653-401 Cannot rename /work/testrestore/production/* to /work/TESTC/*: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

It's as if unix is now trying to move a file named * rather then using * as a wildcard. Is this typical behaviour of shlex?

Edit: I have tried escaping the * with a \, also tried changing from single quotes to double.. not that I expected that to do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For replacing the `*` with what it means, you either need the shell or you need the `glob` module. So the easiest way would be `shell=True` (if the command is constant, I do not see any security holes).

Another approach would be

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import shlex
import glob

cmd = 'sudo rm -rf /work/TEST/*'
arg = shlex.split(cmd)
arg = arg[:-1] + glob.glob(arg[-1])

# This should work now
p = subprocess.Popen(arg)
```

or, if you would nevertheless append the path by yourself,

```
cmd = 'sudo rm -rf'
basearg = shlex.split(cmd)
arg = basearg + glob.glob(path+"/*")
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to have solved the issue - I've used glob as some of my calls contain user input (which is checked before it's allowed by I find paranoia to be a good thing when it comes to security).

Do you know the reason this needs to be done? I assume it's to do with how subprocess handles commands when not just passing them straight to the shell but it strikes me as odd that wildcards wouldn't be able to be handled by it.

Comment: No, that is just because the `*` has a special meaning which must be applied in order to become effective. Normally, this expansion is performed by the shell. As we don't use them here, we must do it by another way. `glob` is the simplest way to do so; you could as well manually provide a list of files in the given directory