# Using ls in Python subprocess.Popen function

Tags: python, subprocess, ls

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-v', self.localDbPath+'labris.urls.*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line != '':
        print line
    else:
        break
```

When using the above code I get the error saying:

```
ls: /var/lib/labrisDB/labris.urls.*: No such file or directory
```

But when I dıo the same from shell I get no errors:

```
ls -v /var/lib/labrisDB/labris.urls.*
```

Also this doesn't give any error either:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-v', self.localDbPath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line != '':
        print line
    else:
        break
```

Why is the first code failing? What am I missing?

Comment: maybe using like this will solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997048/python-subprocess-wildcard-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) is done by the shell. So when you're running `ls *` in a terminal, your shell is actually calling `ls file1 file2 file3 ...`.

If you want to do something similar, you should have a look at the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module, or just run your command through a shell:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ls -v ' + self.localDbPath + 'labris.urls.*',
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

(If you choose the latter, be sure to read the [security warnings](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)!)

Answer (score 5):

You get error because python *subprocess* could not be able to expand * like *bash*.

Change your code like that:

```
from glob import glob
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-v'] + glob(self.localDbPath+'labris.urls.*'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Here is more information about glob expansion in python and solutions: [Shell expansion in Python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482135/shell-expansion-in-python-subprocess)