# Why are commands executed via subprocess.call( ) different than commands executed via terminal?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, call

I'm running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 2 and I wrote a simple Python script to copy all `.png` files from my home directory (`~/`) to a predetermined USB drive.

The command I run in terminal works:

```
cp -r *.png /media/KINGSTON/
```

In python I have the following:

```
from subprocess import call

# Some code

call(['cp', '-r', '*.png', '/media/KINGSTON/'])
```

But when I run the script it says

```
cp: Cannot stat `*.png' : No such file or directory
```

I'm definitely in the right directory when  I try to copy it. `pwd` gives the correct results and `ls` shows all the correct `.png` files.

Comment: It's because there's no shell being specified. If you add `shell=True` to your arguments it should work. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for the docs, and do note that you should not accept user input to anything that uses `shell=True`.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997048/python-subprocess-wildcard-usage

Comment: If it really says "Cannot stat '.png*'", then you have some funky non-printing characters in your string that are messing things up. It *should* say "Cannot stat '*.png'" - that is to be expected, as @Bo102010 points out. If that's just a typo in your question, then never mind...

Comment: @twalberg it was a typo.

Comment: @Bo102010 This is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @HiteshDharamdasani This is an example of of the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @Bo102010: don't use `shell=True`, and you don't even need a subprocess here: use `glob` and `shutil` Python modules instead: `for path in glob('*.png'): copyfile(path, '/media/KINGSTON/')`. If you want recursive behavior then you could use `recursive` parameter and `**`in Python 3.5+ (or `os.walk` + `fnmatch.filter` or `pathlib.Path.rglob`).