# subprocess module on python FileNotFoundError

Tags: python

I am getting 
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output([r'dir',r'C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\WS*'])

Directory of C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads

04-02-2014  20:59        11,682,838 WS BPEL 2.pdf
09-04-2015  04:22         7,758,832 WS-BPEL 2.0 Beginners Guide.epub
10-04-2015  20:33        19,605,151 WS-BPEL 2.0 Beginners Guide. Juric.pdf
16-08-2015  18:58    <DIR>          WSDL
               3 File(s)     39,046,821 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  243,993,673,728 bytes free
```

What am i doing wrong here

Comment: `check_output(cmd, shell=True)`. Subprocess is not aware of `*`. Shell is.

Comment: Hi Rogalski thank you ,Can you make this as an answer please so i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if You write full, correct name in Your path instead of wildcard? still not working, have You tried?
If still want to use it look at this answer:
[Python subprocess wildcard usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997048/python-subprocess-wildcard-usage)

Comment: Thanks for the answer its an enlightenment for me :)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough but what I mean is if it does not work only with wildcard or at all? That info makes difference in looking for solution :) and by the wildcard usage says exactly You to use shell=True :), but before using that answer has to be sure it works at all :)