# Using a glob to generate arguments with subprocess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I want to use metaflac (https://linux.die.net/man/1/metaflac) command from within a python script.

```
from subprocess import run

flac_files = "/home/fricadelle/Artist - Album (2008)/*.flac"
run(['metaflac', '--add-replay-gain', flac_files])
```

I get

```
The FLAC file could not be opened.  Most likely the file does not exist
```

or is not readable.

if I add shell = True to the run function I'd get:

```
ERROR: you must specify at least one FLAC file;
   metaflac cannot be used as a pipe
```

So what do I do wrong? Thanks!

PS: of course the command works fine in a shell:

```
metaflac --add-replay-gain /home/fricadelle/Artist\ -\ Album \(2008\)/*.flac
```

Comment: This is yet another duplicate. For the love of God start closing-as-duplicate and stop answering duplicates till the cows come home... it's only polluting SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify `shell=True` (and as a first approximation, you should never specify `shell=True`), the arguments you provide are passed as is, with no shell expansions, word-splitting or dequoting. So the filename you pass as an argument is precisely `/home/fricadelle/Artist - Album (2008)/*.flac`, which is not the name of any file. (That's why you don't need to add backslashes before the spaces and parentheses. If you specified `shell=True` -- and I repeat, you really should avoid that -- then you would need to include backslashes so that the shell doesn't split the name into several different words.)

When you type 
`flac_files = "/home/fricadelle/Artist - Album (2008)/*.flac` unquoted in a shell, the shell will try to expand that to a list of all the files whose names match then pattern, and will then pass that list as separate arguments. Since `subprocess.run` doesn't do this, you will have to do it yourself, which you would normally do with [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html). For example,

```
from subprocess import run
from glob import glob
flac_files = "/home/fricadelle/Artist - Album (2008)/*.flac"
run(['metaflac', '--add-replay-gain'] + glob(flac_files))
```

Note: unlike the shell, `glob.glob` will return an empty list if the pattern matches no files. You really should check for this error rather than invoke `metaflac` with no filename options.

Answer (score -1):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997093/5249889) for a better explanation.

Globbing doesn't work the way you're expecting it to here, you need to specify `shell=True`, but then you'll need to drop the list.

```
run('metaflac --add-replay-gain ' + flac_files, shell=True)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Using `shell=True` with parameterized / non-constant content folded into the shell script portion is a really, *really* bad idea (it's possible to use `shell=True` safely, but only when content is either quoted with `shlex.quote()`/`pipes.quote()` before being added to the string, or added to the argument list out-of-band from that string). If you're getting your filenames from an upload folder, and someone creates an artist named `$(rm -rf ~)`, then you just had an Extremely Bad Day. See the big red section in https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: (...and more creative names that defy easy attempts at quoting are possible; consider the directory created by the command `mkdir $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''`).

Comment: ...also, it doesn't look like `flac_files` is quoted by the code here, so the spaces inside the name would be split into separate words by the shell -- that is, it would look for a file named `/home/fricadelle/Artist`, then one named `-`, then one named `Album`, then try to expand the glob `(2008)/*.flac`.

Comment: @charles: and the parentheses are also going to be a problem.