# Rsync, used from Python subprocess.run(), cannot read source (works from bash)

Tags: python, linux, rsync

I'm trying to use rsync from Python. I'm calling it with subprocess.run(). (From what I have read, if I use subprocess.popen(), my program doesn't wait for execution to finish, and I want it to wait.) I'm copying the /boot partition and the system partition, with some excludes. (Those are the only two partitions on the drive.)

The command line version of the two rsync commands I'm using are:

`/usr/bin/rsync -aAXv --dry-run /boot/* /media/nboot/`

`/usr/bin/rsync -aAXv --dry-run --exclude=/boot/* --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/home/* --exclude=/home/pi/tmp/* --exclude=/lost+found/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/sys/* tmp /* /media/nsys/`

For reference, I'm creating a list in Python for the actual call and to create these commands I used `' '.join(rsync_boot)` (or rsync_sys), so there's no room for typos. I then copied the commands from the terminal, where they were printed out, and pasted them. Both commands worked just as they should in bash.

The actual calls I'm making in Python are:
`info = subprocess.run(rsync_boot, text=True, capture_output=True)` and
`info = subprocess.run(rsync_sys, text=True, capture_output=True)`.
After the call, I pass info to a subroutine that prints info as a whole, then prints info.stdout and info.stderr.

I get this output for the first one:

`Rsync Boot info: CompletedProcess(args=['/usr/bin/rsync', '-aAXv', '--dry-run', '/boot/*', '/media/nboot/'], returncode=23, stdout='sending incremental file list\ncreated directory /media/nboot\n\nsent 18 bytes  received 47 bytes  130.00 bytes/sec\ntotal size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)\n', stderr='rsync: link_stat "/boot/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]\n')`

(That's directly printing the object returned from the subprocess.run() command, using `text=True, capture_output=True` in the call.)

The output from stdout is:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory /media/nboot

sent 18 bytes  received 47 bytes  130.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

The output from stderr is:

```
rsync: link_stat "/boot/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
```

For the 2nd one (syncing / and using excludes), the returned object, when printed, is this:
`Rsync System info: CompletedProcess(args=['/usr/bin/rsync', '-aAXv', '--dry-run', '--exclude=/boot/*', '--exclude=/dev/*', '--exclude=/home/*', '--exclude=/home/pi/tmp/*', '--exclude=/lost+found/*', '--exclude=/media/*', '--exclude=/mnt/*', '--exclude=/proc/*', '--exclude=/run/*', '--exclude=/sys/*', 'tmp', '/*', '/media/nsys/'], returncode=23, stdout='sending incremental file list\ncreated directory /media/nsys\n\nsent 18 bytes  received 46 bytes  128.00 bytes/sec\ntotal size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)\n', stderr='rsync: link_stat "/home/pi/tmp" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync: link_stat "/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]\n')`

The output from stdout is:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory /media/nsys

sent 18 bytes  received 46 bytes  128.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

And the output from stderr is:

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/pi/tmp" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Note that there is a 2nd error here. Even though I have excluded "/home/*" it is, for some reason, still trying to read "/home/pi/tmp." I'm not clear why it wants to read anything in a directory tree that's excluded.

The common error for both is that rsync is not able to properly handle the source directory, even though it exists and it can be read fine when I run the command for either version from bash.

I have read that sometimes there are issues with the '*' character in this situation. If so, that would be an issue for the excludes as well. Also, I have read about using `shell=True` and that it can be a security risk. I'm building up the commands I'm using within the program, without using external output for any source material, so I'm wondering if that might be a good fix in this case, since there's no input to sanitize.

This gives me with 3 questions:

1. How can I get rsync, when run this way, to see and be able to work with the actual source directories?
2. If the asterisk is an issue, won't it also be an issue for the excludes? And if so, how do I address that?
3. In this situation, without user input, would `shell=True` be a good solution?

Comment: Your post is contradicting itself. You say the command is `/usr/bin/rsync -aAXv --dry-run /boot/ /media/nboot/`, but the exception you have says you've actually executed `['/usr/bin/rsync', '-aAXv', '--dry-run', '/boot/*', '/media/nboot/']` (extra asterisk after `/boot/`).

Comment: @AKX: Odd. I didn't try it without the asterisk. I'll fix that. I probably deleted it while typing and editing.

Comment: Yeah, looking at that, in the bash shell I was using, the * is there, so I must have deleted it by accident while editing. Good catch!

Comment: Arguably this is a duplicate of [subprocess wildcard usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997048/subprocess-wildcard-usage). Note in particular the answers discussing `glob.glob()` should one want a glob to be expanded by Python.

Comment: @tink The problem there is that it's using subprocess.popen(). While the two may work similarly, it's not clear in there if it works for run() as well. But we have an answer that made a difference here already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I get rsync, when run this way, to see and be able to work with the actual source directories?

The easiest: don't use a wildcard (that would regularly be expanded by the shell) with the actual source/target specifications.

`rsync /boot /media/nboot/` (with the rest of the extra flags) will be enough; adapt for the other command. (You may need to fiddle with whether `/boot` or the target has a trailing slash, I can *never* remember how the behavior changes with or without the slash.)

> 2. If the asterisk is an issue, won't it also be an issue for the excludes? And if so, how do I address that?

No. Those patterns are evaluated by `rsync` itself, and *not* having them expanded by the shell is the correct thing to do. On the command line, you'd want to pass them as `--exclude '*foo*'` (the single quotes preventing the shell from expanding the wildcards).

> 3. In this situation, without user input, would shell=True be a good solution?

See point 1 - it's not necessary.

By the way, you might want to add `, check=True` to your `.run()` call, so `subprocess` raises an exception if the subprocess fails.

Comment: I forgot to add this into my list of questions at the end, but do you have any idea why, if I have /home/* as an exclude, it's trying to read /home/pi/tmp? (And I'm testing your solution now - simple fix!)

Comment: Likely because you've specified the relative path `tmp` as source, not the absolute `/tmp`, and your program's working directory is `/home/pi`.

Comment: If you don't want ambiguity, make it `/boot/.` as the source; that way any potential to create `/media/nboot/boot` is unambiguously prevented.

Comment: Okay, thanks on the tmp issue. (I have a reading disability - it is so freaking easy for me to miss little things like that. Imagine how hard it was languages that end lines with semi-colons and I used a colon and the compiler wasn't clear! It could take me a long time to track that down!)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks. I thought the trailing slash on the end of the destination path did that, but a bit extra to ensure accuracy never hurts! (And if I'm wrong about the trailing slash, feel free to let me know.) And I take it that'd work with the command to do that for the main system as well?