# Python script : Running a script with multiple arguments using subprocess

Tags: python, arguments, subprocess

My question is related to this  earlier question - [Python subprocess usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242828/python-subprocess-and-running-a-bash-script-with-multiple-arguments)

I am trying to run this command using python

**nccopy -k 4 "http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis2/pressure/air.2014.nc?air[408:603][2][20:34][26:40]" foo.nc**

When I run the above command I should be able to see a file called foo.nc on my disk or a network error stating unable to access that URL or remote URL not found.

Currently the ESRL NOAA server is down - so when I run the above command I get

syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting SCAN_ATTR or SCAN_DATASET or SCAN_ERROR
context: ^
NetCDF: Access failure
Location: file nccopy.c; line 1348

I should get the same error when I run the python script

This is the code I have and I am unable to figure out exactly how to proceed further -

I tried splitting up "-k 4" into two arguments and removing the quotes and I still get this error nccopy : invalid format : 4

Results of print(sys.argv) data.py

['data.py', '-k', '4', 'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis2/pressure/air.2014.nc?air[480:603][20:34][26:40]', 'foo.nc']

```
import numpy as np

import subprocess

import sys

url = '"http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis2/pressure/air.2014.nc?air[408:603][2][20:34][26:40]"'

outputFile = 'foo.nc'

arg1 = "-k 4"

arg3 = url 

arg4 = outputFile


print (input)

subprocess.check_call(["nccopy",arg1,arg3,arg4])
```

Comment: first of all, use [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html), secondly use `Popen()` instead of `check_call()` if possible. Also your problem is that you don't separate `-k` and `4`. Subprocess automatically tries to insert a space for each parameter element. Try this `["nccopy", '-k', '4']`

Comment: Also when calling system commands traditional shell logic still applies, meaning `" ` will enable parsing of variables and characters where as `' ` does not around parameters in the command. Unless you want parsing of the parameter I'd say use `' ` to wrap parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two dilemmas here.
One being that subprocess processes your arguments and tries to use `4` as a separate argument.

The other being that system calls still goes under normal shell rules, meaning that parameters and commands will be parsed for [metacharacters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-quoting-mechanisms.htm) aka special characters. In this case you're wrapping `[` and `]`.

There for you need to separate each parameters and it's value into separate objects in the parameter-list, for instance `-k 4` should be `['-k', '4']` and you need to wrap parameters/values in `'...'` instead of `"..."`.

Try this, `shlex.split()` does the grunt work for you, and i swapped the encapsulation characters around the URL:

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import sys
import shlex

url = "'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis2/pressure/air.2014.nc?air[408:603][2][20:34][26:40]'"

outputFile = 'foo.nc'
command_list = shlex.split('nccopy -k 4 ' + url + ' ' + outpufFile)

print(command_list)

subprocess.check_call(command_list)
```

Comment: If `outputFile` has a space in it; your code example fails. There is no reason to use `shlex.split()` here (and [it can be fooled in the general case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386775/subprocess-call/14386815#comment45736245_14386815)). It is convenient to use `shlex.split()` in a REPL (to create a seed arguments list from a shell command, that you can fine-tune manually later)—avoid it in the final code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - can you write an alternate answer that is completely different to the other two ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of arg1 = "-k 4", use two arguments instead.

```
import subprocess


url = 'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis2/pressure/air.2014.nc?air[408:603][2][20:34][26:40]'

outputFile = 'foo.nc'

arg1 = "-k"
arg2 = "4"
arg3 = url 
arg4 = outputFile

subprocess.check_call(["nccopy", arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4])
```

See also here [Python subprocess arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679936/python-subprocess-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working shell command that runs a single program with multiple arguments and you want to parameterized it e.g., to use a variable filename instead of the hardcoded value then you could use `shlex.split()` to create a list of command-line arguments that you could pass to `subprocess` module and replace the desired argument with a variable e.g.:

```
>>> shell_command = "python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv)' 1 't w o'"
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split(shell_command)
['python', '-c', 'import sys; print(sys.argv)', '1', 't w o']
```

To run the command using the same Python interpreter as the parent script, `sys.executable` could be used and we can pass a `variable` instead of `'1'`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import sys
import subprocess

variable = random.choice('ab')
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-c', 'import sys; print(sys.argv)',
                       variable, 't w o'])
```

Note:

- one command-line argument per list item
- no `shlex.split()` in the final code
- there are no quotes inside `'t w o'` i.e., `'t w o'` is used instead of `'"t w o"'` or `"'t w o'"`

`subprocess` module does not run the shell by default and therefore you don't need to escape shell meta-characters such as a space inside the command-line arguments. And in reverse, if your command uses some shell functionality (e.g., file patterns) then either reimplement the corresponding features in Python (e.g., using `glob` module) or use `shell=True` and pass the command as a string as is. You might need `pipes.quote()`, to escape variable arguments in this case. [Wildcard not working in subprocess call using shlex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7156892/4279)